# Updating Button Title w/ Boolean Variable Swift

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, uibutton

I'm trying to figure out how to properly configure a follow/unfollow button in a similar fashion to Instagram.

First I've created an IBOutlet for the button and used didSet to define its properties:

```
@IBOutlet weak var followButtonOutlet: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        if !following {
            followButtonOutlet.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
            followButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = Colors.indexedPrimary
        } else {
            followButtonOutlet.setTitle("Unfollow", for: .normal)
            followButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = Colors.indexedPrimary
        }
    }
}
```

Along with the button is a boolean named **following**, that returns true if the user is on the following list, or false if they're not:

```
unc checkIfUserIsFollowing(){
    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let userID = user.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUID).collection("following").document(userID).getDocument { snapshot, err in
        
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            if snapshot.exists == true {
                self.following = true
            } else {
                self.following = false
            }
        } else {
            print("Error retrieving document: \(err)")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is **getting the button title and action to update based on whether or not the user is on the following list.** If the user is not being followed, the button should say "Follow", and "Unfollow" if the user is being followed . Whats the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a didSet on the outlet that attempts to set your button title to follow/unfollow. That logic doesn't make sense there, since your outlet will get set once when you load your view controller's views.

You should move that code to a didSet on your `following` bool. That way, when you change the value of `following` it will run and update the button appropriately.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was just that simple mistake for me. Thanks man

Comment: Sometimes we all have blinders and fail to see the simple stuff. I've been there plenty of times. Glad I could help.